# Posting array of coordinates to database via php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, coordinates

I have an app where I can post data to a database and retrieve it, Im posting an array of coordinates from which I gathered from the movement of the user location, e.g.

```
"37.351701,-122.105898",
"37.351945,-122.106109",
"37.352183,-122.106338",
"37.352409,-122.106568"
```

If the array has around 180 lines, it doesn't get posted to the database, or if Im tracking the user from which the coordinates are gathered from for over 3 minutes also doesn't get added. Im having trouble understanding why this is, I can manually add 300 lines of coordinates that I can take out of the NSLog to the database and retrieve it but not by posting it from xcode via php.

How Im creating the array of coordinates

```
if ((oldLocation.coordinate.latitude != newLocation.coordinate.latitude) &&
        (oldLocation.coordinate.longitude != newLocation.coordinate.longitude))

    self.trackCoord = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f",newLocation.coordinate.latitude, newLocation.coordinate.longitude];

        if (!self.trackArray) {
        self.trackArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    [self.trackArray addObject:self.trackCoord];
```

Im using this to post the array

```
-(void) shareRoute:(NSString*) to withName:(NSString *) from withName:(NSString *) name withName:(NSString *) type withName:(NSString *) duration withName:(NSMutableArray *) trackArrayList{

if (from != nil && to != nil && name != nil){

    NSMutableString *postString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:shareURL];

    [postString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"?%@=%@", Sfrom, from]];
    [postString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"&%@=%@", Sto, to]];
    [postString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"&%@=%@", Sname, name]];
    [postString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"&%@=%@", Stype, type]];
    [postString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"&%@=%@", Sduration, duration]];
    [postString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"&%@=%@", StrackArray, trackArrayList]];

    [postString setString:[postString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:postString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    postConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];        
}

}
```

and this

```
- (IBAction)shareButton:(id)sender{

    [self shareRoute:toLabel.text withName:fromLabel.text withName:routeNameTextField.text withName:typeLabel.text withName:durationLabel.text withName:trackArray];
    [toLabel resignFirstResponder];
    toLabel.text = nil;
    fromLabel.text = nil;
    routeNameTextField.text = nil;
    typeLabel.text = nil;
    durationLabel.text = nil;
    trackArray = nil;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"Test1" object:self];

}

}
```

php code

```
$name = $_GET["name"];
$from = $_GET["from"];
$to = $_GET["to"];
$type = $_GET["type"];
$duration = $_GET["duration"];
$trackArray = $_GET["trackArray"];


$query = "INSERT INTO routes VALUES ('', '".mysql_real_escape_string($name)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($from)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($to)."', '$type', '$duration', '$trackArray')";
```

In the database I tried using `TEXT` and `MEDIUMTEXT` values for `trackArray`.
MySQL table.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `routes` (
`routeID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`from` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`to` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`type` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`duration` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`trackArray` MEDIUMTEXT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`routeID`)
);
```

All other data is being posted successfully, Im also posting other arrays with multiple lines and data but its too much to show so using the above as an example.

Any ideas why the array of many lines is not being added?

Comment: What's the type structure of the table you're trying to insert it into?

Comment: @CianGallagher Updated the question with the table

Comment: Have you checked the variables in your PHP file to see if data is being assigned to them? It could be the case that xcode isn't passing it correctly, or at all. Try echo out the variables, or write them to a log file.

Comment: @CianGallagher I setup php to write to a .txt file, 150 lines worth worked, but over 200 lines .txt file was empty, so Im guessing the issue is with xcode passing the array over, the array is working as it should because I can show a NSLog of it. Any ideas?